# MySQL table_cache refuses to change value

Tags: mysql, percona

For some really weird reason, both of my `table_cache`  as well as `query_cache_limit` values in the `my.cnf` file refuses to change value even though I've modified them.

e.g in mysqltuner the following recommendation is shown:

```
query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
table_cache (> 400)
```

However in the my.cnf file I have:

```
query-cache-limit              = 8G
table-open-cache               = 2048
```

I've restarted mysql, apache and the server yet the values refuse to be updated. I'm using the Percona 5.5 drop in mysql server.

Any tips or suggestions are really welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because are possibly changing the global config file, it is quite possible that the values you set are overridden by a more specific config file, as [stated in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000)

> Keep in mind that even if MySQL does locate a my.cnf file in /etc/my.cnf (global to all MySQL servers on that machine), it will continue its search for a server-specific file, and then a user-specific file. You can think of the final configuration settings as being the result of the /etc/my.cnf, mysql-data-dir/my.cnf, and ~/.my.cnf files

You could either remove any values set in the more specific files, or set the value in the mysql user's specific config file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
Is there solution?

As mentioned @NDM in his answer, i tried to search another cnf files

```
find / -type f -name *.cnf*
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
/etc/mysql/conf.d/my5.6.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/etc/texmf/fmt.d/50cyrtexinfo.cnf
/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.6/examples/my-default.cnf
/root/.my.cnf
/var/lib/mysql/auto.cnf
```

In any of this files no mysql settings overloads. So i'm confused.
Also I change innod_db_buffer_pool_size and it changed after mysql restart! But table_open_cache not!

**UPDATED after half hour**

I found the solution!
It's all because debian system open file limit setting. 
You can change it as described here
https://wied.it/blog/increase-max-open-files-in-debian-squeeze-too-many-open-files-ulimit-n-limits-conf.html

Or here
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/

```
# ulimit -n 4096
Relogin and verify:

# ulimit -Sn # soft limit
# ulimit -Hn # hard limit
```

After that mysql restart.